# Matrix Synapse : get recent messages on particular room

Tags: client-server, message, matrix-synapse

I have to get recent messages from all users on particular room (Matrix Synapse).

When I using this API request:

```
https://m.example.com/_matrix/client/v3/sync?access_token=TOKEN
```

or with the next batch ID:

```
https://m.example.com/_matrix/client/v3/sync?access_token=TOKEN&since=NEXT_BATCH
```

I'm getting a lot of data, but no message bodies in content (only session IDs, ciphers, keys etc.).

Looking for the methods like in Telegram or Discord APIs, when I get explicitly all data about events in one request including body content itself.